# Overriding delete operation on Azure Mobile Services table

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I'd like to override delete operation on my Azure Mobile Services table to make it more like update then real delete. I have additional column named `IsDeleted` and I'd like to set it's value to `true` when delete operation is executed.

I figured out, that what I need is:

- fire my own 'update' inside `del` function,
- delete current `request.execute()`
- prepare and sent response by myself

That meens my `del` function should look like that:

```
function del(id, user, request) {
    // execute update query to set 'isDeleted' - true

    // return standard response
    request.respond();
}
```

As you can see I'm missing the first part of the function - the update one. Could you help me writing it? I read [Mobile Services server script reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj554226.aspx) but there is no info about making additional queries inside a server script function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically two ways to do that - using the [tables object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj614364.aspx), and using the [mssql object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj554212.aspx). The links point to the appropriate reference.

Using mssql (I didn't try it, you may need to update your SQL statement):

```
function del(id, user, request) {
    var sql = 'UPDATE <yourTableName> SET isDeleted = true WHERE id = ?';
    mssql.query(sql, [id], {
        success: function() {
            request.respond(statusCodes.OK);
        }
    });
}
```

Using tables (again, only tested in notepad):

```
function del(id, user, request) {
    var table = tables.getTable('YourTableName');
    table.where({ id: id }).read({
        success: function(items) {
            if (items.length === 0) {
                request.respond(statusCodes.NOT_FOUND);
            } else {
                var item = items[0];
                item.isDeleted = true;
                table.update(item, {
                    success: function() {
                        request.respond(statusCodes.OK, item);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Node.js driver for SQL Server](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/node-sqlserver) that you might want to check out.

The script component of Mobile Services uses node.js. You might want to check out the session from [AzureConf](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/WindowsAzureConf/2012) called [Javascript, meet cloud](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/WindowsAzureConf/2012/B06)